# How should I go about reverse-engineering this printhead?

Tags: circuit-analysis, reverse-engineering

I'm interested in using the Epson FA04010 printhead in a project. I'm pretty sure it uses piezo-based inkjet tech, and I can see in the product images it has 21 pins. I can't find any specs at all for this printhead, which makes sense from the part of Epson. But is there any way to reverse-engineer it to figure out how to drive it? 
[image]

Comment: 1) Two weeks in the lab will save you an afternoon on Google 2) if you have the printer try probing it in operation 3) some of these require interesting waveforms

Comment: You may want to read about this project, if you haven't already: http://spritesmods.com/?art=inker